# Superscript exponents in log scale using Bokeh

Tags: python, data-visualization, bokeh

I am using Bokeh to plot my research study data. I use the log scale a lot. But by default, the axis label of the log axis is shown like 10^2, instead of a superscript 2. The example plot from the Reference doc is exactly so: https://docs.bokeh.org/en/latest/docs/gallery/logaxis.html

I have checked answers to similar questions, and it seems one can use Latex to format the label (https://github.com/bokeh/bokeh/issues/6031). But the solution seems too complicated and it is hard to find out exactly how.

I wonder if there is a simple solution to this issue.

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 2):

***Note from maintainers**: Initial built in LaTeX support was added in version 2.4, see this new answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/69198542/3406693*

---

LaTeX can be used to add a label on top of the existing plot. Right now, it cannot be used for axes' titles.

However, [the comment](https://github.com/bokeh/bokeh/issues/6031#issuecomment-339112770) from the issue that you've linked attempts to solve it in a different way - by just using special superscript symbols.

Here's my attempt to make that solution shorter and easier to read:

```
p.yaxis[0].formatter = FuncTickFormatter(code="""
return 10 + (Math.log10(tick).toString()
             .split('')
             .map(function (d) { return d === '-' ? '⁻' : '⁰¹²³⁴⁵⁶⁷⁸⁹'[+d]; })
             .join(''));
""")
```

Comment: Thank you a lot for the answer. So there is no superscript feature added yet to the package. How do you input the superscript ⁰¹²³⁴⁵⁶⁷⁸⁹ directly into the codes?

Comment: @ZhanhaoHu It's equivalent to `"\u2070\u00b9\u00b2\u00b3\u2074\u2075\u2076\u2077\u2078\u2079"`. However, if you keep your files in UTF-8 and send this info in `Content-Type`, there shouldn't be a problem with using UTF characters in you source files directly.

Answer (score 0):

As of Bokeh 2.0, passing `y_axis_type="log"` to `figure` automatically displays exponents on log axes in a nice way:

[image]

For more complicated scenarios, Bokeh 2.4 adds support for LaTeX (and MathML) to some elements in Bokeh, including axis labels. You can now use `plot.xaxis.axis_label = r"$$10^2$$"`, for example (using [MathJax delimiters](http://docs.mathjax.org/en/latest/basic/mathematics.html#tex-and-latex-input)).

Currently, you can use LaTeX on axis labels, tick labels, div widgets, and paragraph widgets. LaTeX support for more elements should be added soon. For more information about the new math text feature and how to use them, see the [Bokeh 2.4 release blogpost](https://blog.bokeh.org/bokeh-2-4-6f8a842dfb4f), the new [blackbody radiation example](https://docs.bokeh.org/en/latest/docs/gallery/latex_blackbody_radiation.html), and the [Bokeh user guide](https://docs.bokeh.org/en/latest/docs/user_guide/styling.html#adding-mathematical-notations)!

[image]